# Metamask generated signature | verification works when calling erecover function in remix but not in golang

Tags: go, ethereum, solidity

I am trying to verify a signature generated in metamask with go-web3.

Solidity verification code

```
contract Verify {

    function VerifyMessage(bytes32 _hashedMessage, uint8 _v, bytes32 _r, bytes32 _s) public pure returns (address) {
        bytes memory prefix = "\x19Ethereum Signed Message:\n32";
        bytes32 prefixedHashMessage = keccak256(abi.encodePacked(_hashedMessage));
        address signer = ecrecover(prefixedHashMessage, _v, _r, _s);
        return signer;
    }

}
```

I am able to successfully recover the signer in metamask and web3js, but in golang I am getting an incorrect return address.

Golang function

```
func VerifySignature(_data global.SignatureData, walletAddress string) bool  {

   web3, err := web3.NewWeb3(global.AvaxRpcURL)

   if err != nil {
      log.Println(err)
      return false
   }

   avaxMainnetChainId := int64(43113)
   if err := web3.Eth.SetAccount(config.PrivateKey); err != nil {
      log.Println(err)
      return false
   }
   web3.Eth.SetChainId(avaxMainnetChainId)
   tokenAddr := "0xF686F5D7165e8Ce1C606978F424a2DBd4a37e122"
   contract, err := web3.Eth.NewContract(constants.VerificationABI, tokenAddr)

   fmt.Println(_data.HashedMessage, _data.V, _data.R, _data.S)

   if err != nil {
      log.Println(err)
      return false
   }

   msg := [32]byte{}
   copy(msg[:], []byte(_data.HashedMessage))

   num := _data.V
   v, err := strconv.Atoi(num)
   if err != nil {
      log.Println(err)
      return false
   }

   r := [32]byte{}
   copy(r[:], []byte(_data.R))

   s := [32]byte{}
   copy(s[:], []byte(_data.S))

   signer, err := contract.Call("VerifyMessage", msg, uint8(v), r, s)
   if err != nil {
      log.Println(err)
      return false
   }

   log.Println(signer, walletAddress)

   if signer.(common.Address).String() == walletAddress {
      return true
   }

   return false
}
```

I am thinking I am doing something wrong with the function paramaters, all variables come in as a string and I am converting them to the correct types.

I have verified that my data is correct, and my inputs are correct as strings. Web3 go requires the paramaters to match the abi perfectly so I suspect my conversions may be the issue.

Comment: first of all, in your solidity snippet the `prefix` variable is unused; this can cause inconsistencies in your hashed message. secondly, if you could provide some dummy input data for debugging purposes